# finding the minimal date_time within a window of time using sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im trying to model some data using sql, the column i would like to generate is date_started - all others is given.

date_started =  the minimal date_created with the same id1 and id2 in range of 2 hours
that not belong to any other group of rows.

for example, for date_created =  2021-11-02 05:23:41.769,
date_started = 2021-11-02 05:23:41.769 itself.

because 2021-11-02 04:10:39.823 is in range of two hours but belong to 2021-11-02 02:16:28.544 group already.

| id1 | id2 | date_created | date_started |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-11-02 02:16:28.544 | 2021-11-02 02:16:28.544 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-11-02 02:52:52.504 | 2021-11-02 02:16:28.544 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-11-02 04:10:39.823 | 2021-11-02 02:16:28.544 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-11-02 05:23:41.769 | 2021-11-02 05:23:41.769 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-11-02 06:33:11.564 | 2021-11-02 05:23:41.769 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-11-02 08:30:14.564 | 2021-11-02 08:30:14.564 |

Comment: I believe this must be done in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit unclear what you mean as your description could be interpreted differently from what is done in your example (should a new session start whenever there is a 2h gap between the previous "first" activity or whenever there is 2h of no activity?). Either way I think looking into [sessionization](https://knowledge.dataiku.com/latest/courses/advanced-code/python/sessionization.html) might be helpful here (includes lots of example code) as this is ultimately what you're trying to do.